# Python randomly matching two arrays, e.g. Owners and Gifts

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, random

Suppose I have two arrays

```
people = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
gifts = ['toms', 'dicks', 'harrys']
```

and I want to randomly assign a person to a gift, however I don't want to assign them to their own.

I've had trouble because solutions like random.choice don't know about the constraint of not picking a person's own gift. My current hack is to just shift the gifts list by random(1, n-1) but obviously thats not that random.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious? Any common way to do this?

Comment: And you know pair by position in lists ?

Comment: Choices like ` {'tom': 'dicks', 'dick': 'toms'}` are also a problem

Comment: How big are the given lists? Hundreds? Thousands? Not even fit into RAM one piece?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that no one gets more than one gift (if they can you might check out `itertools.product`). The trick is for every person find any "valid receivers" to apply `random.choice()` to. The main criteria seems to be that you can't give to yourself or to the person who gave to you:

I'm sure there are going to be more efficient solutions, but this will get you started:

```
import random

givers = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry', "joe"]
receivers  = givers.copy()
receivers_givers = {}
for giver in givers:
    # ---------------------
    # You can't give to yourself or to the person who gave to you.
    # ---------------------
    valid_receivers  = [reciever for reciever in receivers  if reciever not in (giver, receivers_givers.get(giver))]
    # ---------------------

    receiver = random.choice(valid_receivers)
    receivers.remove(receiver)
    receivers_givers[receiver] = giver

for reciever, giver in receivers_givers.items():
    print(f"{giver} gifts to {reciever}")
```

That should give you something like:

```
tom gifts to joe
dick gifts to harry
harry gifts to tom
joe gifts to dick
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
import random

people = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry', 'arne']
gifts = ['toms', 'dicks', 'harrys', 'arne']

# assign each person a gift randomly but not at the
# same index and don't repeat the same gifts twice so remove them

gift_dict = {}
for people_index in range(len(people)):
    gift_choice = people_index
    while gift_choice == people_index:
        gift_choice = gifts.index(random.choice(gifts))
    gift_dict[people[people_index]] = gifts[gift_choice]
    gifts.pop(gift_choice)

print(gift_dict)
```

output

```
{'tom': 'harrys', 'dick': 'arne', 'harry': 'dicks', 'arne': 'toms'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle one of your lists, then you can `zip()` them. This should solve the issue without having to worry about memory.

```
import random
people = ['tom', 'dick', 'harry']
gifts = ['toms', 'dicks', 'harrys']
random.shuffle(gifts)
results = dict(zip(people, gifts))
print(results)
```